# Azure Oauth - how to change token expiration time?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0

We are using Oauth2 with Azure. And by default server returns token with an hour interval for expiration. Is there any way change expiration interval?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is now possible to configure the token lifetime. You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.

Remark: This feature is in preview and will not go to production in this way. The following header is also placed on the documentation link I mentioned above.

> After hearing from customers during the preview, we're planning to replace this functionality with a new feature in Azure Active Directory Conditional Access. Once the new feature is complete, this functionality will eventually be deprecated after a notification period. If you use the Configurable Token Lifetime policy, be prepared to switch to the new Conditional Access feature once it's available.

Original answer:

<s>Currently there is no way to change the expiration interval. These are the current expiration times.</s>

- Access tokens last 1 hour
- Refresh tokens last for 14 days, but

  - If you use a refresh token within those 14 days, you will receive a new one with a new validity window shifted forward of another 14 days. You can repeat this trick for up to 90 days of total validity, then you’ll have to reauthenticate
  - Refresh tokens can be invalidated at ANY time, for reasons independent from your app (e.g. user changes password). Hence you should NOT take a dependency on the above in your code – your logic should always assume that the refresh token can fail at any time
  - Refresh tokens issues for guest MSA accounts last only 12 hours

Source: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/03/20/azure-ad-token-lifetime/ and also my own experiences.

Comment: Is the expiration interval for Access Token and Refresh Token is configurable now?

Comment: Yes, things appear to be configurable now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Comment: can anyone tell me where should I click in the azure dashboard to get to those settings?? Can't see any references

Answer (score 5):

You have to use power shell to perform 2 steps as below:

1. Create new policy. This policy sets timeout 2 hours

   `New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"02:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "MyWebPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"`
2. Apply this policy to your website

   `Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id <ObjectId of the ServicePrincipal> -RefObjectId <ObjectId of the Policy>`

Note:
In order to get ObjectId of the ServicePrincipal, run this command: `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`

To get ObjectId of the Policy, run this command: `Get-AzureADPolicy`

For more detail you can refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Comment: Official source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Comment: @amzdmt Is it possible to change expiration time through Azure portal instead of PowerShell. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about Azure AD, AFAIK it is not possible to do so.

However, in the response along with token you get back a `refresh token` as well that can be used to get a new token. What you can do is cache the `refresh token` and `expiry time` and before making a request you can check if the token has expired (or about to expire). In that case you make use of this refresh token to get a new token and then make your request.